# Confusion with modelling shortest paths using linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

When looking around for formulating the shortest path problem as a LP I found this:

[https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/22LinearProgramming.pdf](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ers/AlgsDS07/22LinearProgramming.pdf)

At slide 39 they give an example

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iccn2.png)

But in my eyes, this solution doesn't satisfy the inequalities.
For example,

```
x_7 + 44 <= x_t 
with x_7 = 15 and x_t = 50 leads to 
59 <= 50
```

What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Those inequalities look backwards. If $x_t$ is the shortest distance to node $t$ then any other path to node $t$ should be greater than or equal to that. Therefore, we should get that $x_7+44\ge x_t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint inequalities all seem to be backwards to me. Take the first one, $x_s+9\leq x_2$.  We know a way to get from $s$ to $2$ in $9$ so the shortest path to $2$ is *at most* the shortest distance to $s$ plus $9$.

The constraint should read $x_2\leq x_s +9$.